# Mark a method as NOT localized - .NET

Tags: asp.net, localization

I am writing extensions to a web app that doesn't need to be localized.  As the company grows I believe there is a possibility that there may be some effort in the future to do this localization.

Mindful of that I would like to mark all of the place that I am using country-specific date formats in an attribute on the method, for example:

```
            For Each exception As String In exceptionDates
                Dim DateBits() As String = exception.Split("/")
                dates.Add(New Date(Integer.Parse(DateBits(2)) _
                               , Integer.Parse(DateBits(0)) _
                               , Integer.Parse(DateBits(1))))
            Next
```

Any suggestions on either what attribute to use, a generic attribute, or some other mechanism (other that putting a funky comment in the code 'NOTLOCALIZEDMOFO!).  .NET 3.5 mixed language app.

Comment: Ideally when the company decides to introduce localization in the application, the appropriate unit tests should be added to verify that the codebase properly supports this functionality. The tests will fail at first, but start to pass as the relevant code sections are refactored. What you are trying to do is to foresee requirements that might be added in the future, which I think is a waste of time (even if your intentions are no doubt good).

Comment: Being an employee at a small business, us programmers are leaned on much more for developing requirements and anticipating large hurdles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` where possible.

In particular, you should replace that code with `dates.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(exceptions, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));`

Comment: Hey that's a lot better than the code I was using, thanks for the tip.